# Modifying primitive data types through reflection

Tags: java, variables, reflection, field, primitive

I'm currently studying reflection(independently), I'm working with the Field class and I've figured out how to obtain the name and value of a declared variable; however, I'm looking to modify the variable through the Field object I'm instantiating. 
Here is my code:

```
public void handleOutput() {
    try {
        Field f = getClass().getDeclaredField("test");
        f.setInt(int.class, 1);
        System.out.println(f.getName()+": "+f.get(this));
        System.out.println("test: "+test);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException | NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Through this method though an IllegalArgumentException is being thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set int f
```

ield Main.test to java.lang.Class
        at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(
Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(
Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.setInt(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Field.setInt(Unknown Source)
        at Main.handleOutput(Main.java:13)
        at Main.main(Main.java:28)
Press any key to continue . . .

How would I modify the value of the primitive int data type test using the declared field?

Comment: Have you read the javadoc? What does `Field#set` expect as its first argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you mean

```
f.setInt(this, 1);
```

Comment: Wow, that's pretty embarrassing. I'm a little confused on the entire usage of the this keyword in this scenario, could you possibly explain why this line of code works?

Comment: @Dan The `Field` is a property of the `Class` not of the instance. In order to make changes for a particular instance you need to pass the instance you want to act upon into the method. In this case, that instance is the same as `this` so that is what you pass in.